# Translating from Maple to Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple, number-theory

Sorry if this question doesn't fit the site well... I have been trying translate a bit of Maple-code into Mathematica. I don't know Maple at all but I do know some Mathematica. I really don't know what I am doing so I wonder if someone could help me just a bit:

```
b:= proc(n, s) local sn, m;
  if n<1 then 1
else sn:= [s[], n]; m:= nops(sn);
     `if` (m*(m-1)/2 = nops (({seq (seq (sn[i]-sn[j], 
          j=i+1..m), i=1..m-1)})), b(n-1, sn), 0) +b(n-1, s)
  fi
end:

a:= proc(n) a(n):= b(n-1, [n]) +`if` (n=0, -1, a(n-1)) end:

seq(a(n), n=1..30);
```

I think I understand everything except

```
sn:= [s[], n];
```

but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The indexing call `s[]` returns the sequence of the entries of `s` if `s` is a list or a set.

For `s` of type list (in particular) the call `s[]` behaves like the call `op(s)`. (Note that this similarity in behavior is true for lists, sets, and sequences. But it's not true for all types.)

```
L:=[2,4,7]:

L[];

                        2, 4, 7
op(L);

                        2, 4, 7

[L[], 5];

                      [2, 4, 7, 5]
```

So `[s[], n]` takes list `s` and creates a new list. The new list, which gets assigned to `sn`, contains the entries of list `s` followed by `n`.